# MySQL IF ELSE queries

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to create a query which is based on the result from another query and i want to do all of that through SQL if possible.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT `item1` FROM `table1` WHERE {conditions})
THEN
UPDATE `table2` SET {columns} WHERE {conditions}
ELSE
INSERT INTO `table2` SET {columns} WHERE {conditions}
```

The SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT queries are tested and work separately. I would post an exact code, but the queries are too long and full of variables that wouldn't make sense without context. I just need to know if this is possible at all and if use the correct syntax for it. If not, what is it? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you best testing for existing in one table, but inserting into another?

Comment: Did you consider reading the manual? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff the two tables are related and have dependent fields. The first one contains id from the second. Condition is if related id is not assigned - create a new one and assign it. Else update

Comment: @ChrisKitching yes i did and i did not understand it. That is why i am asking here